# Randomly generate a sorted set with uniform distribution

Tags: random, sampling

I have an ordered set $S = \langle S_1, S_2, .., S_M \rangle$ from which I want to draw a sample of $N$ elements in such a way that the sample is non-strictly totally ordered (as with $\leq$ and the integers), and all the possible occur **with equal probability**. The sample must be taken with repetition.

For example, let's say $S = \langle 1, 2, 3, 4 \rangle$ and $N=3$, the samples:  $[1, 1, 1]$, $[1,2,3]$, $[2,3,3]$ would be valid, but $[3,2,1]$ or $[2,1,1]$ would be invalid.

A simple way to generate this set would be to just randomly sample from $S$, and then sort the resulting sequence. However, please note that the following approach is biased  ($[1,1,1]$ is less likely to occur than  $[1,2,3]$, for example).

This question is related to one of the answers given in this StackOverflow question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26467434/generating-random-number-in-sorted-order. Note that the algorithm proposed there is to generate such a sample without repetition, whereas I want my sample to be generated with repetition.

Comment: Is it easy to compute precisely how biased this "simple" method is? (As an example, $[1,2,3]$ is six times more likely than it should be in your case.) If so then you can achieve an unbiased method by randomly rejecting some of the outputs of this "simple" method. This would probably be rather slow, but if you don't really need particularly high speed then that's not a problem. If you need faster than you'll need to be a bit more clever.

Comment: In any case, does the simple algorithm "randomly pick $s_1$ from $S_1,\dots,S_M$, randomly pick $s_2$ from $s_2,\dots,S_M$, ..." give a biased result as well? (By the way, are you sure it makes sense to do this problem in the setting of just a partial order? For a partial order not all samples can be sorted...)

Comment: @Ian, this "correction" method is something I've been thinking of. However, I couldn't figure out how to compute this bias in the general $N$, $M$ case. Any help with that would be much appreciated! As for your second comment, I do not understand the sample techniques you're describing. It appears to me as if you are just picking the elements in order, but that wouldn't be a random sample. Finally, by partial order, I meant something like <= for integers (which is actually the real problem I'm trying to solve). Please let me know if my naming is incorrect so I can adapt the question.

Comment: If you're talking about a totally ordered set then the bias is straightforward to compute: a particular sample will have its probability multiplied by the number of permutations of that sample that exist, which is easily obtained by using factorials. As for my second idea, the point is to randomly select elements of your sample in order from among those that you're still allowed to select based on the sorting requirement. Again this is reliant on the order being total.

Comment: @MarcusRitt Note that the interval is always *closed*, so $\langle 1,2 \rangle$ can indeed give $[1,1]$ in that approach.

Comment: And no, $\leq$ on the integers is a total order. Your problem is always isomorphic to the problem of selecting integers, so you can just call it that rather than trying to come up with the right abstract terminology.

Comment: Sorry about that. Then I was talking about a nonstrict total order. Let me ammend my question to reflect that. In that case, how would you adapt the bias computation you just described for something like $\leq$?

Comment: It's just the way I described it: for example, the bias on $[1,2,3]$ is $6$ whereas the bias on $[1,1,2]$ is only $3$. In general the bias is $\frac{N!}{\prod_j n_j!}$ where $n_j$ is the number of times $j$ appears in the sample. But for large $N$ this rejection-based method will reject the incredibly overwhelming majority of samples, so it wouldn't surprise me if it were prohibitively slow. I still think sampling elements one after the other according to the ordering restriction will work.

Comment: @Ian, my idea was to use this bias computation so that I can generate the sequence by correcting the bias *on-the-fly*. But I still have to give it a bit more thought... Anyway, thanks for the help so far!

Comment: One way to use the bias on the fly would be to do Metropolis-Hastings. For example, you can generate a method for generating a random multiset of size $N$ drawn from $S$ which updates the multiset by deleting a randomly chosen element from your current multiset and adding a new randomly chosen element to replace it. It's easy to see that this generates multisets uniformly at random in the long run even though there are short term correlations.

Comment: (Cont.) The bias in the sorted sequences would then be $\frac{N!}{\prod_j n_j!}$, which you can then mitigate in the usual Metropolis-Hastings way: accept a change from $\mathbf{n}$ to $\mathbf{n'}$ with probability $\frac{\prod_j n_j!}{\prod_j n'_j!}$ and otherwise stay at $\mathbf{n}$. Now you can generate random multisets with the desired bias, and then just sort them to finish.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's enough to pick $N$ random elements from $\{ 1, 2, \ldots, M+N-1 \}$ without replacement and then do a postprocessing step.  Say you pick $T_1 < T_2 < \ldots < T_N$; then let $S_K = T_K - K + 1$.  For example with $M = 4, N = 3$, this is like picking $3$ random elements from $\{1 ,2 , \ldots, 6\}$.  So for example you might pick $T = \langle 1, 4, 5 \rangle$ and then $S =  \langle 1 - 1 + 1, 4 - 2 + 1, 5 - 3 + 1 \rangle = \langle 1, 3, 3 \rangle$.

So you need an algorithm for picking random subsets of a given size.

To pick a random subset of size $k$ of the set $\{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$, there's a nice recursive algorithm.  Such a set includes $n$ with probability $k/n$.  If it includes $n$, then take the set to be a subset of $\{1, 2, \ldots, n-1\}$ of size $k-1$, with $n$ adjoined; if it does not include $n$, then the remainder is a subset of $\{1, 2, \ldots, n-1 \}$ of size $k$.  (I learned this algorithm from the late Herb Wilf's notes "East Side, West Side", available online at https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/eastwest.pdf - see page 16 for code.  It's in Maple, but should be reasonably understandable.)

Comment: Must the $T_K$ be sorted? If not then $T_2$ could be $1$ and then you have a problem.

Comment: Also you should obviously have $T_N$ not $T_M$.

Comment: This is a very elegant solution! As @Ian mentioned, the first random subset must be sorted for this to work, but other than that it worked fine and was very easy to implement in code, thanks!

Comment: I intended for the $T_K$ to be sorted, but it's not obvious from the notation.  I will edit accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

I would just draw $3$ random numbers and only accept ones in ascending order, that way you have equal probabilities (i.e. rejection method as discussed)

Otherwise,

Sample the triples by using monte carlo. I.e. count how many different combinations are permissible, and accept each with equal probability according to different values of a $U[0,1]$, i.e. give $111$ the range $[0,1/n]$, $211$ is $[1/n, 2/n]$. As long as you have some sensible ordering on the set of possible sequences you are in business. You can use for loops to achieve this.

Comment: For moderately large $N,M$, the first approach is very slow due to acceptance being rare, while the second approach is slow to get started because there will be many such sorted sequences to handle.

Comment: Hmm yes agree first approach is kind of standard rejection sampling with low acceptance. For second one you could probably just compute $nU$ with $U$ the standard uniform and then  take integer part. Then you can just pass this to an array containing all of the sorted sequences in order.

Comment: Can make function from naturals $\leq n$ to sequences by doing a recursive function